# Is it a Geforce GTX 1650 Mobile or a Max-Q?

Tags: graphics-card

I just ordered a laptop which was supposed to run a Geforce GTX 1650, but I'm thinking it might be a Max-Q.

I'm confused about the output of this command:

```
john@john-laptop:~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] <-- Mobile / Max-Q ? Mobile or Max-Q ?
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:138 memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I've seen the Max-Q was around 20% less powerful but uses less energy and weighs less so I'm not sure it's a bad thing, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are truly using the Max-Q version of the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile.

From the article
[NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Max-Q](https://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-1650-Max-Q-GPU-Benchmarks-and-Specs.418763.0.html) :

> The Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q design is a mobile graphics card that is based on the Turing architecture (TU117 chip). Compared to the faster RTX 2000 GPUs (e.g. RTX 2060), the 1650 integrates no Raytracing or Tensor cores. Compared to the desktop version, the mobile and Max-Q versions use all 1024 shaders of the TU117 chip. It is designed for thin and light laptops and about 10-15% slower than a regular GTX 1650 for laptops (depending on the cooling capabilities). According to the specifications, the Max-Q variant clocks 20% slower for the base speed and 27% for the boost speed.

Comment: How can you tell from the OP's question? There are 2 different versions using the TU117  chip. https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-1650-mobile.c3367 and https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-1650-max-q.c3383.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Only your first link is for the Mobile version. The important part here is explaining to the poster that his card is truly the GTX 1650 Mobile, and that Max-Q denotes a sub-model.

Comment: The 2nd link is **also** a mobile version "The GeForce GTX 1650 Max-Q is a mobile graphics chip". Note that the two links have different performance figures ... see https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/nvidia-tu117.g881

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yes, the title threw me off. But that isn't the question.

Comment: I know that the Max-Q is also mobile, but the Max-Q isn't called the Mobile Max-Q.
How did you know about your answer ? Does the "Mobile / Max-Q" part of the command mean Mobile / Submodel Max-Q ?

Comment: So the output on a regular Geforce 1650 Mobile would be `product: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile]` ?

Comment: It would be whatever name the video driver had supplied the operating system. The official name is usually the one given by the manufacturer.